# Give an alert when only button is double clicked

Tags: jquery

When double clicked two `records` were adding. So in this scenario an `alert` message should come and records should not add. Records should add only button click and also if I want to add more `records` it should get to be add. I can't `disable` the button, without disabling I need to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Have you attempted this? Please share your code.

Comment: I have an add button to add the drugs, so when i am adding drugs if button is double clicked then the same drug adding two times. so when button is double clicked i need an alert message.

Comment: I know the answer but I can't share it as you have not shown that you have researched...

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.omkaar.k

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dblclick() method if you want to get an alert message by double-clicking on an element

For example:

```
$( "#hello" ).dblclick(function() { 
alert( "Hello World!" );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Igor Shcherbinin, alert was coming but the same time duplicate records also adding.